# Trouble getting unique List elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to extract unique elements from a list of Classes with the format:

```
[EntityClientPlayerMP['Player989'/228, l='MpServer', x=138.16, y=68.62, z=522.96], EntityCow['Cow'/231, l='MpServer', x=143.63, y=68.00, z=527.50]....]
```

these lists typically have a size of 60-100.

The method I am trying to use at the moment is

```
List<Class> uniqueList = new ArrayList<Class>(new HashSet<Class>(fullList));
```

this returns the exact same list, but sorted a bit differently. Any ideas on why?

Comment: What do you mean by "sorted a bit differently"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: What does your `Class` class look like? (I assume you don't mean `java.lang.Class`?)

Comment: This sounds a lot like a "_I didn't implement hashCode() and equals()_" issue.

Comment: The sorting isn't an issue for me, I was confused as to why it would return a sorted version but not just the unique elements,as in it did an operation on the List to sort but not remove duplicates.

Other comments have shown that I dont know enough about implementing hashcodes, so I'm looking into that at the moment

I have explained my use of Class in a comment below.

Answer (score 3):

They are ordered differently because `HashSet` has "weird" ordering, based upon the hashCode of the Objects.  To preserve ordering, use a `LinkedHashSet`.

As for the uniqueness, the Set will use `equals()` and `hashCode()`, so be sure those are implemented correctly.  A lazy technique that sometimes works is to use the `toString()` method of your objects (and call the hashCode and equals on the Strings).

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide correct implementation for `equals()` and `hashcode()`

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to override the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) methods in each of your entity classes ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)), otherwise the set won't be able to properly determine when two elements are equal. Also, I think you meant this:

```
List<EntityClientPlayerMP> uniqueList =
    new ArrayList<EntityClientPlayerMP>(
        new LinkedHashSet<EntityClientPlayerMP>(fullList));
```

Now in the above snippet the type parameter is one in particular (not `Class` as shown in the question, replace with the actual type as needed), and by using [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) we guarantee that the ordering in the original list is preserved.

Comment: The example list does not only include `EntityClientPlayerMP` but also `EntityCow`. Presumably these are subtypes of OP's `Class` type.

Comment: @Arend  In that case you'd want Object.

Comment: What I meant is, apparently the OP has defined his own type `Class` of which `EntityClientPlayerMP` and `EntityCow` are subtypes. Of course, this is just idle speculation, and hardly relevant to the question (to your answer of which I have nothing to add).

Comment: It's quite possible that OP is using `Class` as an example, a placeholder for the real classes, so let's ignore that and focus on the question

Comment: I am infact refering to Class, as this List is used in a mod for the game minecraft to search for enemies by their Class, an inbuilt method in the code asks for a Class as an argument. I am not sure if this is right or not, being a fairly new coder, but it works in the way I expected. Is using Class not a good idea? I am trying to post the method in this comment but there is not enough space, whats the best way to show it?

Comment: Edit the question and add the details. And no, it doesn't seem to be a good idea to have a list of classes. All of the instances share the exact same class!